# Create index for each value concatenated using aggregate function in Qgis

Tags: indexing, expression, gis, aggregate-functions, qgis

This is my first post in stack overflow. I would be more than happy if you could help me out with the following issue I have:

I am using qgis calculator, and specifically, the aggregate function, to obtain the names (id) of cables that run through my ducts layer, as sometimes there are more than one cable running through the ducts. The code is as follows:

```
aggregate(
   layer:='cables',
   aggregate:='concatenate', 
   expression:= to_string(name), 
   concatenator:=',',
   filter:=within(geometry(@parent),buffer($geometry,0.2))
)
```

This code populates a field in my ducts layers called 'cables' and looks like this:

```
CLS00083,CLS00084,CLS000309
```

[image: example]

I now want to index each value that has been populated so that it looks as follows:

```
1:CBL00083,2:CBL00084,3:CBL000309,4:CBL000310 etc.
```

[image: example]

**Is there a way to achieve this using the aggregate function?**

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
array_to_string (
    with_variable (
        'array',
        
            aggregate(
                layer:='cables',
                aggregate:='array_agg', 
                expression:= to_string(name), 
                concatenator:=','
            ),
            array_foreach (
                @array,
                (to_int (array_find (@array, @element))+1) || ': '  ||  @element
)))
```

I suppose cables and ducts are on different layers. If not, you could use the easier `array_agg` function instead of `aggregate`, something like:

```
array_to_string(
    with_variable (
        'array',
        array_agg(to_string(name)),
        array_foreach (
            @array,
            (to_int (array_find (@array, @element))+1) || ': '  ||  @element
)))
```

By the way: for GIS-related questions, [better use GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, cables and ducts are different layers. For some reason the piece of code you have sent doesn't seem to work (It is a valid expression but doesn't return the name field), it returns an empty list for all rows. Any idea as to why? Thank you beforehand

Comment: Sorry, forgat an `array()` statement - see updated answer, that should work.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but where should I put the array statement? I'm quite new with this qgis expressions. I have tried placing it just before the aggregate function but it throws the following result [ '1:' ] for each row, and where there's cable it throws [ '1:CBL000155,CBL000154' ] . Thank you, Fran

Comment: I tried the new version you have just edited but seems to be happening the same. Thank you. Fran

Comment: Did you try with the second version `array_agg` (updated now)?

Comment: I have tried but because cables and ducts are different layers it doesn't work either

Comment: Yes, no luck unfortunately

Comment: I guess I saw the problem, even though not having the settings and project that you have, it's a bit tricky to guess. Instead of aggregate function `concatenate`, use `array_agg` so that you directly get an array. Creating one from a concatenated string is tricky. Please try the revised expression (sorry for confusion).

Comment: I have tried the new version, had just had to add the filter to make it work correctly. It works now, thank you a lot. Do you recommend any good resources to learn qgis advanced expressions apart from official documentation?

Comment: Hm, I learned it mainly using the help in the expression editor where each funtion is explained in detail. See also Advanced QGIS Expressions video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXPCec8vgLA